# How to create a pivot table over a range containing dynamic arrays?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have my raw data in Column C. In Column E I have a dynamic array `=UNIQUE(C4:C9)`. Now, I would like to create a pivot table whose data source is this dynamic array in Column E.

When the height of the dynamic array changes (because the value of the raw data change), I would expect the pivot table to automatically adjust its data source to refer to the entire dynamic array.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could try to use Name function to get a dynamic data source.

Answer (score 0):

[Table_Pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUIFC.png)

may be try to convert your Raw to Table and make pivot out from your raw data and click refresh, as what I tried see image attached.

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid you did not understand my question.

Comment: You want your Pivot table source from an array to expand your data dynamically as you update your Raw data. I give you a suggestion that instead of creating your array and creating your pivot too.